# Magento 2 : var/Generation Magento Tutorial

Tags: magento2, cache, code-generation, bin-magento

Can you Suggest any tutorial for `var/generation` and Patterns in Magento 2.

Please Provide video Related materials.

**Thanks**

Comment: please accept the answer if you satisfied so other user get a benefit

Answer (score 0):

To re-generate Magento 2 code in var/generation, you should update generated code every time you upgrade Magento 2  or switch between develop and master branches of the official git repository. Although, you can manually delete content of the var/generation folder – Magento 2 will generate code automatically on its next run – the correct way requires triggering the generation via the Magento 2 CLI tool. Therefore, run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`:

*Your Video Materilas For Code Generaion:-*

**Magento Meetup New Delhi - Magento2 Code Generation**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBswqNjhWvM